# how to get records from mongodb through node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here In my mongo collection I have few records. I am writing an API in node js where I pass the ID in request body. My API have to take ID from request body and need to fetch it's whole records in response. but I am getting empty array.

My mongo collection record:

```
[{ accountId:"a1",name:"test"}]
```

My Node js code approach:

```
exports.getById = async (req) =>{
   let id = `"` + req.body.accountId +`"`;
   let accountId = await db.collection('account-details').find({id}).toArray();
   return accountId
}
```

In request body, I am passing accountId as :

```
{ 
  "accountId":"a1"
}
```

The ID is in the form of string. When I am trying to fetch whole records with the provided ID through my API, I am getting response as []. Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: If you think my answer is correct I suggest you change the title of your question to something like: 'how to send a document id with a get request?'. That makes it possible for other people to find the answer as well. And probably add express as a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send a body with an HTTP GET, therefore it will not be available in the `req` object, so `req.body.accountId` will be undefined and `id` will be an empty string.

You need to use POST (or PUT) to send body data.

But the **more usual solution** in your situation is to use GET with dynamic routing, where you add the id to the route e.g.: http://example.com/api/accounts/1234

If you use Express, in your router you need to add the route `api/accounts/:id` to your router. The id will be available in your code as `req.params.id`.

See [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters). For other frameworks this will be something alike.

Hope this helps.